# How to set Content-Encoding when using X-Sendfile to return gzipped files

Tags: apache, x-sendfile

I have gzipped data files and images on disk. I want to serve them with Apache and have the browser unzip them, by setting the `Content-Encoding: gzip` response header. Basically what mod_gzip does, but my data is already gzipped, so I don't need to gzip again before sending.

But I use `mod_xsendfile`. My application is written in Django, it runs behind an Apache proxy. The URL for a data file first goes to Django, which checks permissions and finds the right path for the file on the disk; then a `X-Sendfile: <path>` header is generated that Apache sees, so that it returns the file instead (this is done by the `mod_xsendfile` module).

If I set the `Content-Encoding` header in Django, `mod_xsendfile` strips it; as its documentation says,

> The Content-Encoding header - if present - will be dropped, as the module cannot know if it was set by intention of the programmer or the handler. E.g. php with output compression enabled will set this header, but the replacement file send via mod_xsendfile is most likely not compressed.

So I can't do what I want.

Is there any way to put the header back in for files I want to return like this, probably in the Apache config?